# SSL certificate updated but changes are not visible

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I deleted a previous generated ssl certificate in `/etc/ssl/example.com/` with the files

- example.com.csr
- example.com.crt
- example.com.key

and created a new one with the exact same files but changed content.

Then I typed "update-ca-certificates" via command line.

When I type `https://example.com/login.php` I still see the old certificate...

How do I reload the new certificate???

Comment: Did you close all instances of your web browser (especially Chrome) and restart it?

Answer (score 1):

OMG. I just forgot to restart the Webserver. That's all.
After changing a certificate...

- "update-ca-certificates" via command line
- Then just restart server